# SQLAlchemy relationship create custom 2 level dict

Tags: sqlalchemy

Дорогое сообщество,

Необходим совет, как создать вложенный словарь, к которому можно доступиться через sqlalchemy.relationship.

1. Таблица: **Parent**

| Column | Description |
| --- | --- |
| id | primary_key |
| parent_id | ForeignKey("**Child.parent_id") |

2. Таблица: **Child**

| Column | Description |
| --- | --- |
| id | primary_key |
| parent_id | primary_key, nullable=True |
| key | primary_key |
| value | *some random value* |

Данные в таблицах создаются отдельно друг от друга.
**На текущий момент связь выглядит следующим образом:**

```
children = relationship(
               "Child",
               primaryjoin="Parent.parent_id == Child.extension_data_id",
                            collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection('extension_data_id'))
```

А хотелось бы вот так, но attribute_mapped_collection этого не предусматривает:(см.параметры attribute_mapped_collection, 2 параметра)

```
children = relationship(
               "Child",
               primaryjoin="Parent.parent_id == Child.extension_data_id",
                            collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection('extension_data_id, key'))
```

Как результат, я хочу получать через
Parent.children = { parent_id: {key : {}, key: {}} ...}

Сейчас же я получаю:
Parent.children = { parent_id: {key: value}...}

То есть мне нужна двух-уровневая вложенность.

Пишу сюда второй раз, не стреляйте - спрашивайте, дополню. Пианист играет как умеет.